# Number of distinct order types corresponding to a finite cardinal number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is from "Theory of Sets" by E.Kamke. This is about **Type classes**. The notion of type classes was given in this paragraph.

[image]

The definition of type class:

> ...We denote by $\mathfrak T_m$ the set of distinct order types which belong to a given cardinal number $\mathfrak m$ , and call this set the type class belonging to $\mathfrak m$ , ...

Then in the footnote , it says:

> Actually , $|\mathfrak T_m| = 2^m$ ; see Hausdorff [1], p. 455.

So , if $\mathfrak m$ is a finite cardinal , like $3$ , then the type class belonging to $3$ will be  $\mathfrak T_3$. And $|\mathfrak T_3| = 2^3 = 8$.

But then , there is another line before this paragraph which says ,

[image]

So this paragraph says that to every finite cardinal number , there corresponds precisely one order type. So , $|\mathfrak T_3| = 1$ ?

At this point I am kind of confused. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Every finite cardinal $m$ only has one order type, indeed and $m!$ ways to realise this order type on a given set of size $m$. The footnote is about *infinite* cardinals only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the footnote forgets to mention that $\mathfrak{m}$ is an infinite cardinal number.

What is true, is that $|\mathfrak{T}_\mathfrak{m}|=2^{\mathfrak{m}}$ for infinite cardinal numbers $\mathfrak{m}$. This is what is mentioned in [Hausdorff's book](https://archive.org/details/grundzgedermen00hausuoft/page/454/mode/2up):

[image]

> The proof that the power of $T(\aleph_0)\geq \aleph$ is by Cantor; that it is $\leq\aleph$ is by Bernstein; both are described in Bernsteins dissertation, *Untersuchungen aus der Mengenlehre* (Halle 1901). The theorem can be generalised without difficulty that $T(\aleph_\alpha)$ has power $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$;

Note that Hausdorff uses $\aleph$ to denote the power of the continuum $2^{\aleph_0}$. In modern usage this is usually called the *cardinality* of the continuum (to avoid confusion with the power operation), and usually denoted with the symbol $\mathfrak{c}$.

One is also more or less obligated to note that $|\mathfrak{T}_\mathfrak{m}|=2^{\mathfrak{m}}$ requires the Axiom of Choice, since without Choice not every infinite set can be ordered, and thus $\mathfrak{T}_\mathfrak{m}$ may be empty.